# Books on ergodic operators

Tags: reference-request, operator-theory, book-recommendation, ergodic-theory

I have been struggling for a long time looking for books discussing ergodic operators and their mean ergodic theorems.

Unfortunately, I could not find like these books.

Therefore, I would be very grateful if anyone could suggest books' names containing what I want.

Comment: The best in that direction should be the book by U. Krengel, Ergodic Theorems, de Gruyter, 1985.

Comment: I would say that it depends on your interests. Is your primary interest operator theory or ergodic theory? For the former the book that you mention should be better, but your question seemed to indicate that you are really interested on the ergodic properties.

Comment: The point is that operator theory ends where many important directions of ergodic theory start, such as entropy theory, but that really depends on your interests. For example, for the discussion of the properties that are of interest today one would rarely use spectra (such as for ergodicity, mixing or Lebesgue).

Comment: If you type ergodic theory or ergodic operators in **Google Image** rather than in Google Web, you will be pleasantly surprised to find images of book covers, professors' handwritten notes, slides, etc. That will shorten your time of searching. Try too Pinterest, lots of gems there. I checked out there and found **tons** of book covers and photos of professors specialising in ergodic theory. Also try Youtube. There, you sometimes find videos of lecturers by professors, NASA scientists, etc.